# What might be causing MySQL to hang my Python script?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I have a pretty straightforward Python script. It kicks off a pool of 10 processes that each:

1. Make an external API request for 1,000 records
2. Parses the XML response
3. Inserts each record into a MySQL database

There's nothing particularly tricky here, but about the time I reach 90,000 records the script hangs.

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host            | db            | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+------+-----------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 44 | root | localhost:48130 | my_database | Sleep   |   57 |       | NULL             |
| 45 | root | localhost:48131 | NULL          | Sleep   |    6 |       | NULL             |
| 59 | root | localhost       | my_database | Sleep   |  506 |       | NULL             |
| 60 | root | localhost       | NULL          | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

I have roughly a million records to import in the way so I have a long, long way to go.

What can I do to prevent this hang and keep my script moving?

```
Python 2.7.6
MySQL-python 1.2.5
```

Comment: How, and how often, are you connecting to the database?  (i.e. are you doing something silly like making a separate database connection for each record write?)

Comment: It would help to see the script.

Comment: @JohnGordon Originally no. I was opening the connection at the beginning of the script, doing the work and closing the connection at the end of the script. I just tried opening and closing the connection with each operation (the silly stuff) and that got me further, actually.

Comment: Maybe the external API is throttling your requests?  Does your script hang on the API read, the XML parse, or the DB write?

Comment: The DB write is the issue, but in limited testing so far, it does seem to be less of an issue when I open and close as I go. I hate to do that, but maybe there's a timeout setting I can tweak. I'll investigate that. I'm pretty sure it's a MySQL problem (not Python), but I wanted to include context in the post.

Comment: Are you using transactions in the DB write?  Do you commit each transaction promptly?

Comment: I think so. `try: do insert, commit() except: rollback()`. Anything seem amiss? I'm not a Python expert.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you have a single process (rather than 10)?

Comment: Are you inserting the 1000 records in the transaction, or is there a single row insert per transaction? What indexes are on the table?

Comment: @TomDalton When I last tried 1 process - several iterations ago, the script took _days_ to run. The current iteration runs 1 record per transaction. The table has no explicitly created indexes at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what I wanted to do, but I have found that opening and closing the connection as required seems to move things along.